# What is my build method within my form_for helper accomplishing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just starting to learn Rails and I'm currently working on a watered down Facebook clone. I'd like to know what exactly my build method that I'm including in my form_for helper is doing. This is taken from [The Ruby On Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-stats_and_a_follow_form) where we did something similar, but with Twitter followers instead of friend requests. I couldn't wrap my head around it then, and I'm still having trouble now.

Here is the form that I'm using when a user sends a friend request to another user. This is a form partial rendered from @users (hence the user.id)

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :friend_id, user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Send Friend Request" %>
<% end %>
```

This passes to my Friendships controller...

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:friend_id])
  current_user.send_friend_request(@user)
  redirect_to current_user
end
```

Which makes a call to `send_friend_reqeust`...

```
def send_friend_request(other_user)
  friend_requests << other_user
end
```

My User model `has_many :friend_requests, through: :active_relationships`

It works fine, but I started questioning what `current_user.active_relationships.build` in my form_for helper was even doing. To my (very) untrained eye, it looks like the form is passing a hidden value of `friend_id` which the Friendships controller then uses to find the User database record associated with that ID.

If all that my form is doing is submitting a hidden User ID, then what is the point of the build method? I know it must do **something** since removing it breaks my program.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is an intermediary model between User and FriendRequest models.

By using method BUILD you create a new ActiveRelationship and through that then you can create new FriendRequest.

User >> ActiveRelationship >> FriendRequest